# Pros & Cons of PostgreSQL and MySQL in Qt?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, qt, postgresql

What would be the pros and cons of PostgreSQL and MySql with the `QSqlDatabase` class in Qt? Is there a preferred database when it comes to connecting remotely with C++?  These are currently my only options, should I seek another?

Answer (score 1):

`QSqlDatabase` is database-agnostic. There may be a few slight differences in how `QtSql` classes behave with the different drivers, but it's still possible to write database-agnostic applications.

I think you *really* should pick what you're most familiar with, unless there's a compelling reason to favor one in particular.

I like PostgreSQL the most because

- works *for me*
- is suitable for my projects
- is mature and reliable
- documentation is fantastic
- community is awesome
- *for me* it's easier to setup
- and yes, I'm a deeply fanatized PostgreSQL fanboy.

In some specific scenarios it might make sense to use SQLite instead.